# DIV jumps to top before content change

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, cordova

I have an iOS web app made with Cordova 3.0.0. In this app I have a div called "mainContainer". When I try to change the content of this div, it jumps to top for a few moments, then the content is changed. 
How can I disable this effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have javascript tagged, I assume the content change happens through a javascript function, and you have control over the code of said javascript function.

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx) should help you maintain your former scroll-position.

In case the article get's deleted at a later date, the essential code posted in it is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>
```